# "I have been done" is this correct?

Tags: grammar

I just heard a song. The lyrics were:

> I've been done, I've been moving on...

In conversation, is that correct grammatically?

Comment: Exactly as you wrote it in your question (the answer provided casts doubt on its accuracy—although neither the question nor the answer attributes it to any source), it's a comma splice: two independent clauses separated by a comma *without* a conjunction. So it's technically ungrammatical—but still acceptable stylistically in fiction and other writing. And both song lyrics and poetry are similarly unconstrained. In *conversation*, there's even less need to adhere to the grammar of formal writing, so it's not clear what you mean by "grammatically."

Comment: Please provide the title of the song, who sings it, and, ideally, a link to the actual lyrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely grammatical in any register. You need to put this in context:

> So I cut you off
>   I don't need your love
>   'Cause I already cried enough
>   I've been done
>   I've been movin' on **since we said goodbye** *(emphasis mine)*

*Done* here is employed as an adjective, not a verb: it means 'finished, over'. The singer is saying he is no longer interested in the relationship (he is 'done' with it) and he **has had** that attitude for some time: "since we said good goodbye". Since that time he has been "movin' on": turning away from the relationship and pursuing other interests.

Comment: If you're going to quote something, you should provide attribution. What's the song, who sings it, and is there a link that can be provided?

Comment: "IDGAF" from "Dua Lipa"